# PHP: How can I apply my variables to a dynamic set of conditions?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, functional-programming, conditional-statements

Consider an array as a set of generic or abstract conditional statements:

```php
$conditionSet = array(
    'condition1' => '$a > $b', 
    'condition2' => '$c != $d', 
    'condition3' => '$f < $e'
);
```

Is it possible to apply the variables that I have in my current scope of execution to the conditions in the array on-the-fly - without having to try and parse the statements?  ***i.e.***

```php
$a = 1; 
$b = 2; 
$c = 3; 
$d = 4;
$e = 5; 
$f = 6; 

if ( $conditionSet['condition1'] && 
     $conditionSet['condition2'] && 
     $conditionSet['condition3'] )
{
    // PASS: do something    
} else {        
    // FAIL: do something else
}
```

Comment: What exactly does your array contain, boolean values?

Comment: Are you talking about an array like.. `array("1+1>5","true","0","10>2*3");`?

Comment: yeah just like what you said. the array is like  array("1+1>5","true","0","10>2*3");

Comment: @BigBeetleFan I've edited your post to try and make it clearer what you are asking for - if there's any statement that you feel is inaccurate can you please amend it further.

Answer (score 2):

you want to use array_reduce.

```
$conditionSet = array(true, false, true);

$conditionReduced = array_reduce
(
    $conditionSet,
    function($a,$b)
    {
        return $a && $b;
    },
    true
);

if($conditionReduced)
{
    echo 'all conditions are true';
}
else
{
    echo 'one or more conditions are false';
}
```

Comment: This is the best method, it also allows you to adjust the test in future to handle other logic or any casting required (string comparison for example).

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you are getting at - the other answers here assumed that your `$conditionSet` is a collection of predetermined booleans which is perfectly plausible but your edit suggests that you want to be able to assert that ***n*** number of parameters match a given set of generic checks at any given time?

Instead of coupling ***state*** to particular parts of your application you could group ***callable*** *"comparison"* functions *(assertions)*.  Although It may not adhere to it strictly in this example I believe this forms - in part - the basis of a [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach.

```php
function assertion(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args[0] as $assert)
        if(!call_user_func_array($assert, array_slice($args, 1)))
            return false;
    return true;
}

$conditionSet = [
    function($a, $b){ return $a > $b; },
    function($a, $b, $c, $d){ return $c != $d; },
    function($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f){ return $f < $e; }
];

if( assertion($conditionSet, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5) )
    echo 'All conditions true';
else 
    echo 'One or more conditions false';
```

[**demo**](http://ideone.com/QKawEW)

Variables `$a` through `$f` could be passed as a single array but I wanted to demonstrate the flexibility.

---

You could of course just use `eval` but frankly that would be Fugly *(capital F)*!  This method is more robust and arguably the proper way to approach your problem.   I also think it's rather pretty but that's subjective :) - I'm not sure how it would affect performance.

You should check out the documentation on [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func) and [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func-array) as they are quite powerful tools.

---

<sup>***The following is just for completeness and should not be used in production code...***</sup>

I should have also pointed out that *PHP* has it's own `assert` function which accepts callable arguments *(admittedly I wasn't even aware of this myself)*  but it doesn't accept a set of several.  In any case here's a simple demonstration:

```php
$a = 2; $b = 3;
if( assert(function($a, $b){ $a > $b; }) )
    echo '$a is greater than $b';
```

If you don't end up reading the [`assert`](https://www.php.net/assert) documentation please be aware there's a part that reads:

> *"... should be used as a debugging feature only ... should not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated."*

I'm not sure if this refers to an option that applies to the the function in it's entirety or just it's ability to evaluate strings *(most likely the former)* - which I'm guessing works in a similar way to `eval`.

See this post on [why `eval` is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951868/1238344).

It's not *100%* clear what your final intention would be, for simplistic comparison this is somewhat overkill but I can see a use for the first solution I posted if you are dealing with more complex logic.

Answer (score 0):

Array array_filter function will filter out all false expression when used without a callback function:

```
if(count(array_filter($conditionSet)) == count($conditionSet)){
    //do somthing
}else{
    //do other
}
```

If all of the conditions are true, the count should match between prefiltered and post-filtered array.